# What is vcs in cache directory in Golang?

Tags: go

I found that in cache directory ($GOPATH/pkg/mod/cache) has vcs directory (image below):

[image: cache directory]

I also found that my company private modules are stored in there (each module has its hashed name directory, info and lock). Especially, in hashed name directory is something like project with git - you can use git log to show every commits).

Does anyone know what is the purpose of this directory and how is it created? Thank in advance.

P/s: `go mod download -x` command shows that zip version of module created from here with `git archive` (can be found on download directory - image above)

Answer (score 2):

See [Go Modules Reference - Module cache](https://go.dev/ref/mod#module-cache):

> `cache/vcs/`
>
> Contains cloned version control repositories for modules fetched directly from their sources. Directory names are hex-encoded hashes derived from the repository type and URL. Repositories are optimized for size on disk. For example, cloned Git repositories are bare and shallow when possible.

Comment: I am grateful to you. But I have one more question. I still don't understand this statement clearly: `Contains cloned version control repositories for modules fetched directly from their sources` -> Supposed that I have https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin dependency in my project, does it mean that gin module is not fetched directly from github source code?

Comment: You're correct for the default configuration. Search for `GOPROXY` and `GOPRIVATE` in the "Go Modules Reference".

Comment: Thank a lot. I get what I want. For those who come later: the detail of this behavior is in section `Version control systems` of Go Modules References. 
TLDR; module will be downloaded from proxy first (not direct). If there is no found in proxy, `go` try to download it module directly from source control (frequently true for private module).

Comment: Most of the time, for private modules, you want to set `GOPRIVATE` to prevent it from trying proxy first.